# Return string using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Below is my problem, i want to set the text of a textbox to be the filename of the WizFile object where the type equals exhibitors...how do i do this?

```
private IList<WizFile> wizFiles;
wizFiles = importerService.GetWizFiles();

txtExhibitors.Text = wizFiles.FileName where wizFiles.Type = exhibitors
```

There will only ever be one WizFile in wizFiles where the type equals exhibitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query returns an `IEnumrable<string>` - you just need one:

```
wizFiles.First(w => w.Type == exhibitors).FileName
```

`First` will return the first item if it exists and throw an exception if the list is empty.

You can use `FirstOrDefault` which, for a `string` will return `null` if the list is empty.

If it is important that there is exactly one item in the list, consider using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes:

```
   txtExhibitors.Text = wizFiles.First(wiz => wiz.Type == exhibitors).FileName;
```

You may want to use FirstOrDefault and check for null before getting the FileName.

Comment: Your answer is very similar to mine +1.